# Comparacion de elementos de dos pilas

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy haciendo un trabajo para mi universidad, esta consiste entre otras cosas en insertar caracateres en 3 pilas, 1 de ellas tiene una secuencia la cual queremos encontrar en las otras 2 pilas.

El problema es que en el metodo `Comparar` que dejaré a continuación me salta un error que tambien tiene que ver con el metodo `pop` de la pila, les dejaré el codigo y el error que salta a ver si me podrían ayudar.

*(el codigo no esta completo, solo tengo la comparacion de la primera pila con la pila secuencia).*

**Clase de la pila:**

```
public class Pila {
    char elementos[];
    int tope;

    public Pila(int n) {
        elementos= new char[n];
        tope = -1;
    }



    public boolean empty(){
        if(tope == -1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean full(){
        if(elementos.length-1 == tope){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void push(char a){
        tope++;
        elementos[tope]=a;
    }

    char aux;
    public char pop(){
       aux= elementos[tope];
       tope--;
       return aux;
    }

    public char peek(){
        return elementos[tope];
    }


    public void mostrar(){
       for(int i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
           System.out.print(elementos[i]+", ");
       }

    }

}
```

---

```
/*metodos de comparacion, copia(ya que tengo que comparar con el pop y no quiero que se e elimine la pila original) y  el main*/

public class Tarea2 {

    //cmetodod para comparar 
    public static boolean Comparar(Pila x,Pila primera){
        // se copian las pilas a comparar
        Pila copia1=copia(x); // pila con secuencia
        Pila copiaprimera= copia(primera);// pila a comparar con la secuencia



       for(int i =0;i<=x.tope;i++){
           copia1.elementos[i]=x.elementos[i];
       }
        for(int i =0;i<=x.tope;i++){
           copiaprimera.elementos[i]=primera.elementos[i];
       }
        int contador=0;

        char c= copia1.pop();
        char b= copiaprimera.pop();

        System.out.println(c);
        // a continuacion se comparan los caracteres de la pila
        while(contador < 3){
        if(c==b){
             c=copia1.pop();
             b=copiaprimera.pop();
             contador++;
         }else{
            b=copiaprimera.pop();
        }
        }
        if(contador==3){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public static Pila copia(Pila original){
        Pila copia = new Pila(original.elementos.length);

        for(int i=0; i<copia.elementos.length;i++){
            copia.elementos[i]=original.elementos[i];
        }
        return copia;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese una serie de caracteres para la primera pila: ");
        String x = teclado.nextLine();

        Pila primera = new Pila(x.length());

        for( int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
            primera.elementos[i]= x.charAt(i);
        }

        primera.mostrar();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Ingrese una serie de caracteres para la segunda pila: ");
        String y = teclado.nextLine();

        Pila segunda = new Pila(y.length());

        for( int i=0; i<y.length();i++){
            segunda.elementos[i]= y.charAt(i);
        }

        segunda.mostrar();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Ingrese una serie de caracteres para la pila secuencia: ");
        String z = teclado.nextLine();

        Pila secuencia = new Pila(z.length());

        for( int i=0; i<z.length();i++){
            secuencia.elementos[i]= z.charAt(i);
        }

        secuencia.mostrar();
        System.out.println();
        // llama a a la funcion para comparar
        System.out.println(Comparar(secuencia,primera));


    }

}
```

Este es el error que me envía:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1    at tarea2.Pila.pop(Pila.java:46)    at tarea2.Tarea2.Comparar(Tarea2.java:32)   at
>   tarea2.Tarea2.main(Tarea2.java:102)
>   C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 22 seconds)

Comment: Como menciona @Angel en su respuesta deberías emplear el método `push` para añadir  elementos y no acceder directamente a su atributo elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que su error se encuentre porque al usar `Comparar` -> `Comparar(secuencia,primera)` este llama a estas lineas en algun punto:

```
    char c= copia1.pop();
    char b= copiaprimera.pop();
```

que se basan en `tope`

```
public char pop(){
       aux= elementos[tope];
```

para funcionar pero `tope` inicialmente es -1, y usted nunca incrementa el `tope`.

quizas tenga que revisar la lineas similares a las siguientes:

---

```
    Pila primera = new Pila(x.length());

    for( int i=0; i<x.length();i++){
        primera.elementos[i]= x.charAt(i); <--
    }

    primera.mostrar();
```

---

```
   for(int i =0;i<=x.tope;i++){
       copia1.elementos[i]=x.elementos[i]; <--
   }
```

---

y ajustalas a algo asi:

```
primera.push(x.charAt(i));

copia1.push(x.elementos[i]);
```

Pues el `tope` solo se incrementa al hacer uso de `push`, por lo que puedo ver y usted cuando añade los elementos nunca usa `push` para ello con lo que `tope` nunca cambia su valor inicial que es `-1`

---

*Nota: no he compilado su codigo.*